# in the diagram, $O$ is the origin of $OC$ and $OD$ find $CD$

Tags: geometry

While doing some past tests for the IGCSE I encountered this question and I couldn't figure out what's the answer to this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrsXM.png).

I found out using the mark sheet that the answer is:
$CD = OC + OD = 6a - 2b$, However I couldn't figure out why.

Furthermore I know a triangle can't have a side that's equal to the other two side combined, and even more

$(-2a + 3b) + (4a + b) = 2a + 4b. $

But

$(4a + b) - (-2a + 3b) = 6a - 2b$

I also couldn't understand what the other question wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE

Case 1:If the tail of second vector $\vec {CD}=r_2=(x_2 i+y_2 j)$ is on the head of the first one $\vec{OC}=r_1=(x_1 i+y_1 j)$ , then $\vec{OC}+\vec{CD}=(x_1+x_2) i +(y_1+y_2) j$

Case 2:If the tail of two vectors are coincident, like OC and OD, then the sum is:

$OC+OD=(x_2-x_1)i+(y_1-y_2)j$ , so we have:

$OC+OD=[4-(-2)]a+ (1-3)b=6a-2b$

For second question the position vector of E is  like case 1 and we can write:

$r=OE=OD+DE=(4+1) a +(1-2)b=5 a -b$ or $\vec r=5i-1j$